# xcode loop to display only one of each state from a list of address

Tags: json, xcode, loops

I have a nsmutable array that returns a companies address.   I currently having the array returning all the States.   But I would like it to only return one of each State.
Current Example:  Ca. Wa. Wa.  Mi.  Ca.  And when I select a state I need to take the info to the next page.   Here is my code so far.

```
- (NSArray *)readCompanies:(NSURL *)url {
    //create a nsurlrequest with the given Url
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:
                             NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];

    //get the data
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

    //now create a nsdictionary from the json data
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                   options:0 error:nil];

    //create a new array to hold the comanies
    NSMutableArray *companies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //get an array of dictionaries with the key "company"
    NSArray *array = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"companies"];

    //iterate throught the array of dictionaries
    for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
        //create a new company object with information in the dictionary
        Company *company = [[Company alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:dict];
        //add the Company object to the array
        [companies addObject:company];

    }

    //return the array of Company objects
    return companies;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark -table view controller methods

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section {
    return [companies count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellID = @"CellIDState";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (cell == nil){
        //single line on table view
        //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellID];
        // dual line on table view
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    Company *company = [companies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //cell.textLabel.text = company.company_id;
    cell.textLabel.text = company.state;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",company.companyName];
    //adds cheveron to tableviewl
    [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you have an NSMutableArray of Company objects. Then you display a table with a button for each Company's state on it.

```
Company 1, CA    -> [CA]
Company 2, WA    -> [WA]
Company 3, CA    -> [CA]
```

If I understand your question correctly, you desire to display only a single cell for each state that has a company in it. That means you need a way to represent more than one company for each state.

One possibility for this is to have a top-level structure as a dictionary, where the key is the state and the value is an array of Company's in that state. The above three Company's would end up in this structure as:

```
NSDictionary
  key1 (CA)
    Company 1
    Company 3
  key2 (WA)
    Company 2
```

The code to do this is a bit more complex than the loop you made. The `readCompanies` for it would look like this (please excuse my rough pseudocode):

```
-(NSDictionary*) readCompanies(NSURL* url) {
  Get URL data
  Parse URL data into array of dictionaries (you have these steps already)
  NSDictionary* companyByStates = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

  //iterate throught the array of dictionaries
  for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    //create a new company object with information in the dictionary
    Company *company = [[Company alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:dict];

    if companyByStates does not have entry for key(company->state) {
      create new NSMutableArray
      add this company to new array
      add array to companyByStates under key (company->state)
    }
    else  // already have entry for that state
    {
      get array for that state: companyByStates[company->state]
      add this company to the array for that state
    }
  }
  return companyByStates
}
```

Also, your `tableView` method would need to use a `[NSDictionary keyEnumerator]` to access the indexed entry since the states are no longer an array, but keys in the top-level dictionary.

Hope that helps.